# Setting angular material date picker value programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using angular material date picker in one of my component's of angular project. This component has two tabs. Using *ngIf I am showing only one at a time based on what user has clicked.In one tab user selects a date and if navigate away to other tab of same component and comes back to previous one, I need to retain the selected date.

This is what I am doing in **HTML side**:

```
<mat-form-field class="dropdownWidth">
      <input #dateInput matInput [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter" [matDatepicker]="picker"
             placeholder="Choose a date"
             [value]="datePickerDate"
             [(ngModel)]="datePickerDate"
             (dateChange)="addDateEvent($event)"
             [disabled]="selectedOperator.length === 0 && userDateRange.length === 0">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

And in **TS file**:

```
addDateEvent(event) {
   this.datePickerEvent = event;
   this.datePickerDate = new Date(`${event.value['_i'].month + 1}-${event.value['_i'].date}-${event.value['_i'].year}`);
   this.formatDate = moment(event.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}
```

But when I navigate back, date value is not retained. Any suggestions how can I achieve this?

Here is sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lwwunp)

Comment: could you create a [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) example?

Comment: that's because when you navigate between tabs, component is rendered again. if you want to persist that value locally you should use localstorage for saving/retrieving value.

Comment: @StepUp I have added the stackblitz link. Here you can see that navigating between tabs the date is not retained.

Comment: @Mridul am always in the same component, the tab item and it's content are in same component, so component is not rendering again, but I checked with your solution also, it didn't worked out

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52799795/4868839) answer could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work because you are not storing a selected value. So create a variable in typescript:

```
yourDate: any;
```

HTML:

```
<p> YourDate  {{ yourDate | date }} </p>

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="yourDate" 
        [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

It is possible to see the [whole code at stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tf3xu7?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I have updated my stackblitz code, with variable in ts file, but now for some reason am not even able to select the date in first place

Comment: I have modified my project code according to your stackblitz link, still for some weird reason it is not working :( am debugging it now.

Comment: @BijaySingh Try to copy and paste code. It should work. Have you tested stackblitz example?

Comment: yes I tested with your code and it helped me. Also I was able to figure it out why it was not working for me, it was because am also using a filter on date picker and that filter is getting is set based on some options being selected before selecting date.

Comment: @BijaySingh I am glad that it helped to you! You're cool as you've found a reason why your code was not working! :)

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are not using any bindings. Try to use `[(ngModel)]`, so that it will take and hold the selected value.

Do like this, it will work:

```
<mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [(ngModel)]="date" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```