# How can I display the saved date in the input field with GET in mat-datepicker?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I have developed a mat-datepicker. I can select a date and save it in the back-end. How do I display the saved date in the input field?

My code:

```
// HTML
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
   <mat-label>Datum</mat-label>
      <label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="financial_year_start" required>
       </label>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          <mat-error *ngIf="settingsContentForm.get('financial_year_start').hasError('required')">Input is required!</mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

```
// TS
dateForm: FormGroup;
 ngOnInit() {
 this.dateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      financial_year_start: [null, Validators.required],
    });
}
```

```
// My JSON
{
    "success": true,
    "mandant": {
        "mandantId": 1,
        "firm": "Test Ltd.",
        "financial_year_start": "Juli 1, 2018" // I want to display this value in the input, but in the format DD-MM-YYYY
    }
}
```

```
// My service for GET Date
public getCurrentMandantData(): Observable<any> {
    const url = `/current-mandant`;
    return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.baseUrl}` + url);
  }
```

Comment: you can use ngModel/formControl for example: have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799604/set-default-value-for-angular-material-datepicker-with-angular-5

Comment: If I understand correclty, you are able to pick a date and save it. But when you load the page and the date was already set before, the date does not appear in your picker?

You need to call getCurrentMandantData() and use the response to update the dateForm

Comment: yes, can you show me how to do that?

Comment: have u try using moment.js to convert it before put it on ngmodel? somthing like -> `moment('Juli 1, 2018').format('DD-MM-YYYY');`

Comment: or somthing like -> `let setDate = moment('Juli 1, 2018').format('DD-MM-YYYY'); this.dateForm.controls['financial_year_start'].setValue(setDate)`

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to do this:

1. in component.ts file
   You should have a variable that hold date value:

   myDate = new Date();

it initialized date with current date. We can change the value later.
2. If you play with observable, then want to assign the value to the date, add toDate() method:

```
this.myDate = this.dateFromObservable.toDate();
```

3. Attach it to template file (html) with [startAt] binding:

   <mat-datepicker [startAt]="myDate">